# How to calculate an annualized rate of return with a number of cash-secured Puts?

Tags: options, put-options, rate-of-return

For cash-secured-puts I know how to calculate the annual return of a single one like:

```
(Returns divided by Capital at Risk) x (365 divided by Holding Period in days)
```

With a "wheel" strategy (selling puts until assignment, selling calls until stocks being called away) how could one calculate the ROI for any number of cash-secured-puts on different stocks, different opening/closing dates, overlapping periods etc.?

Example trades:

```
2022-01-02 Sell 1 AAA Put with Strike 10 and receive 100$ after commissions
2022-01-07 Sell 1 BBB Put with Strike 20 and receive 120$ after commissions
2022-01-10 Buy  1 AAA Put with Strike 10 for 50$ incl. commissions
2022-01-18      1 BBB Put expires out of money
...
```

It of course would eventually also hold trades that ended in an assignment or a realized loss. My aim would be to compare that rate to an index like the S&P500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan A: Search this web site for previous explanations about this.  For example: [How to Calculate Return of Multi Positional Trading Strategy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145624/how-to-calculate-return-of-multi-positional-trading-strategy)

Plan B: Keep it simple. Determine your daily P&L total for these positions based on a predetermined starting date and each day, calculate the ROI based on that starting date.  At the same time, calculate the return of the base index from that same starting date.